# How to open another window and close the current window in GUI?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm new to Graphic User Interface using Python. I was able to open the register page after clicking the Register button from the login page.

Below is the code files:

`login.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from register import Register

class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loginw = Tk()
        self.loginw.title("Login")
        self.loginw.geometry("500x500")
        
        self.signin = Button(self.loginw,width=20, text="Register", command=self.register)
        self.signin.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    def register(self):
        win = Toplevel()
        Register(win)

w=Login()
w.loginw.mainloop()
```

`register.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Register:
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.reg = win
        self.reg.title("Register")
        self.reg.geometry("500x500")
        
        self.revert = Button(self.reg,width=20, text="Return to Login")
        self.revert.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.reg.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to write the code like:

- After clicking the `register` button from the login page, the register page pops up and the login page disappears.
- After clicking the `Return to Login` button from the register page, the register page disappears, and the login page comes back.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you _need_ to destroy one window and open another, or would you like to know how to just reconfigure the current window?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taken from another stackoverflow question:

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

In your case class StartPage could be your register page and PageOne your Login page. take that piece of code as a base to start.

[Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

In this case the SampleApp class acts like the master frame (is a container) for other frames. So there is no pop up windows.

Another base template for tkinter app. Taken from the same link:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Register)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self.geometry('925x600+'+self.screen()+'+20')
        self._frame.pack()

    def screen(self):
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        posX = (screen_width //2) - (925//2) 
        return str(posX)

class Register(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is the register Page").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Login)).pack()

class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Login Page").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.usuario = tk.Entry(self)
        self.usuario.insert(-1, 'User')
        self.usuario.config(foreground='gray')
        self.usuario.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10, ipady=3)

        
        self.password = tk.Entry(self)
        self.password.insert(-1, "Password")
        self.password.config(foreground='gray')
        self.password.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=10, ipady=3)

        tk.Button(self, text="Return to register",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Register)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                  command=lambda: print("not implemented yet")).pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

**edit: to answer another question**:

To change the title (**in the first example**) you must call inside one of these classes StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo

```
controller.title("the title you want")
```

That is because in this part of code (in the class SampleApp, the main class) you are passing itself as second parameter.

```
 self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self) //controller=self
        self.frames[page_name] = frame
```

In the main class (SampleApp) you would do:

```
self.title("Some title")
```

**In the second example:**

```
master.title("Login")   //inside Login or Register
self.title("Something") //inside SampleApp
```

Comment: From the first sample, login page, may I ask how to change the title of the app from "tk" to "Login"?

Comment: For example, inside your class, you can put controller.title("Login"). To set the title inside SampleApp class, you should put self.title("the title you want"). But in the Frames controller.title("something")